# Как просмотреть все назначенные alias git

Tags: git, git-alias

**Как просмотреть(вывести на экран) все назначенные alias git?**
Как вывести на экран все alias для пользователя или для всех пользователей?

*Уточнение*: В данном контексте вопрос задан по git альясам, а не альясам терминала.

Answer (score 1):

`git config --system --list` #просмотр(вывод) всех альясов для всех пользователей системы, в git

`git config --global --list` #просмотр(вывод) всех альясов для текущего пользователя,в git

`git config --list` #просмотр(вывод) всех альясов для текущего репозитория git

`git config --local --list` #для локального репозитория, вход в локальный репозиторий при этом должен быть выполнен

PS. Вы можете добавлять и просматривать альясы не только на уровне git, но и на уровне терминала bash.